# how to insert doublequote inside doublequote on HTML5

Tags: php, html, button

i try do call a PHP function into a HTML 5 button formaction and when i click on the buttun it's didn't work.
here the first code:

```
<button id="Location" type="button" value="LOCATION" formmethod="GET" formaction="<?PHP include'./Function/DisplayFunction/TableViewer.php'; Table("Location");?>" onclick="">LOCATION</button>
```

after i tryed this:

```
<button id="Location" type="button" value="LOCATION" formmethod="GET" formaction="<?PHP include'./Function/DisplayFunction/TableViewer.php'; Table(/"Location/");?>" onclick="">LOCATION</button>
```

and this:

```
<button id="Location" type="button" value="LOCATION" formmethod="GET" formaction="<?PHP include'./Function/DisplayFunction/TableViewer.php'; Table(%84Location%84);?>" onclick="">LOCATION</button>
```

Comment: Now try it with a backslash

Comment: Can you give the outputted HTML code?

Comment: There's far more than just a backslash issue here - it looks like a fundamental misunderstanding of how HTML and PHP work together... There's no reason `formaction="<?php Table("Location"); ?>" ...` would **not** work as the PHP is interpreted long before the HTML, of course it'll depend on what the output of `Table("Location")` actually is. However, embedding `include'./Function/DisplayFunction/TableViewer.php';` inside that `formaction` as well is just ... weird.

Comment: Thank's all but the line didn't work on the code and i should change my method using AJAX code

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash: `\` instead of: `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Include there is going to paste all the contents of that php file into the `formaction` property, surely that's not what you want, try:

```
<?php
include('./Function/DisplayFuncrion/TableViewer.php');
echo '<button id="Location" type="button" value="LOCATION" formmethod="GET" formaction="'.Table("Location").'" onclick="">LOCATION</button>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use double quotes there.

Try this

```
<button id="Location" type="button" value="LOCATION" formmethod="GET" formaction="<?PHP include('./Function/DisplayFunction/TableViewer.php'); Table('Location%'); ?>" onclick="">LOCATION</button>
```